# How to reset an Arduino with node-serial?

Tags: serial, reset, node.js

I was reading about using an [Arduino with a Makefile](http://thinkingonthinking.com/an-arduino-sketch-from-scratch/). In the [Makefile-Arduino](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile) project there is a reference to the Python serial library required to reset the board.
Looking into the usage of PySerial to reset the board, there is some reference to [DTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460865/disable-dtr-in-pyserial-from-code) or [here](http://johanneshoff.com/arduino-command-line.html)

- What is DTR?
- How to control this bit with node-serial and reset the Arduino?